# "reason": "", "status": "500" when trying to log in to the Playstation Store

Tags: psn

When trying to log in to the Playstation Store on my PC, I've been getting the below error message for months now (after entering my username & password):

[image]

I can log in to the same account on my PS3 with no problems. What's going on?

Comment: have you tried pressing F12 and looking at the console for any Javascript error that occur? it looks like a json object was returned but the page doesn't know how to handle it

Comment: Are you using any adblockers/noScript plugins? Have you tried a different browser? Have you tried clearing your offline cache/history etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on @Robotnik's hint, the solution turned out to be the offsite cookie filter addon...

By enabling cookies from `sonyentertainmentnetwork.com` and  `auth.api.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com`, I was able to finally log in.

Comment: glad to be of assistance :-)

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the [HTTP Status Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) for an unexpected error on the server side. To quote the description of 500, `A generic error message, given when an unexpected condition was encountered and no more specific message is suitable.`

It is possible that this is a temporary issue due to a hardware or software failure at Sony. Either way, there is likely nothing you can do beyond waiting for them to fix their server. If it doesn't go away soon, maybe send them an email?

Comment: I should probably add to my question that I've had this problem for months now.